# How I can slove heroku H13?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I've been getting this error now on & off for the past couple days since I deployed my application(Ruby on Rails) to heroku.

```
2019-09-22T15:35:11.196499+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=82376036-bcc3-4f63-8019-1b206e534947 fwd="60.114.58.106" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=908ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2019-09-22T15:35:11.252159+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 134
```

I tried following commands, but I couldn't solve error.

```
$heroku container:rm web
$heroku container:push web
$heroku container:release web
```

I want to know solving H13 error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few ideas since I don't know your exact case:

- If your server (e.g. Unicorn) worker timeout is set to less than 30
  seconds, you could try increasing it to a higher value (but Heroku
  limits this to 30s explicitly).
- If this only happens when you first try to load the application after it has been idle (sleeping) for some time, then this is expected. The subsequent requests should be fast though.
- If you're performing long processes within the HTTP request context
  and they frequently take more than 30 seconds to complete, you might
  want to consider using a background job manager (e.g. Sidekiq for
  Ruby) to run such processes in the application background.

Answer (score 0):

**H13 - Connection closed without response**

This error is thrown when a process in your web dyno accepts a connection, but then closes the socket without writing anything to it.

One example where this might happen is when a Unicorn web server is configured with a timeout shorter than 30s and a request has not been processed by a worker before the timeout happens. In this case, Unicorn closes the connection before any data is written, resulting in an H13.

A couple lines up, you have an error about a process timing out after say 15s:

```
ERROR -- : worker=1 PID:8 timeout (16s > 15s), killing
```

Heroku help has a section on timeout settings:

In Unicorn you can set a timeout in config/unicorn.rb like this:

```
timeout 15
```

The timer will begin once Unicorn starts processing the request, if 15 seconds pass, then the master process will send a SIGKILL to the worker but no exception will be raised.

P.s. If you are getting above error in one request so you can try below steps -

```
-> push the API call to background job
-> submit the form as ajax
-> In the action which handle submit, trigger the background job and render the job_id , the path to which need to be redirected and other parameter you want to reuse
-> On success of ajax request, trigger another ajax call to a separate method which keep checking the status of the job after a fix interval say 3 seconds.
-> when the second ajax call see that status is complete, it will reload the page
```